# insertar un dígito y la siguiente inserción sea el dígito consecutivo (mediante condición)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Trabajo en un proyecto en C#, el cual tiene una condición de que cada que sea día 1ro del mes me inserte el valor "1" y lo que quiero lograr es que una vez insertado el dígito 1 la siguiente inserción sea su consecutivo, solo he logrado que se inserte 1 cada vez que doy clic.

Podrían orientarme un poco?

codigo ejemplo:

```
protected void aumentoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count = int.Parse(folioTextBox.Text);
        count++;
        folioTextBox.Text = count.ToString();
        fechaTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        string fol = folioTextBox.Text;
        string fecha = fechaTextBox.Text;
        string fechaopr = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
        string fechanw = "01";
        string folcmp = "1";

        conexion.Open();


        if (fechaopr == fechanw)
        {
            string cadena2 = "insert into Folios(Folio, Mes) values ('1','" + fecha + "')";
            SqlCommand comando2 = new SqlCommand(cadena2, conexion);
            comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folio", fol);
            comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", fecha);
            comando2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        else
        {
            string cadena1 = "insert into Folios(Folio, Mes) values ('" + fol + "','" + fecha + "')";
            SqlCommand comando1 = new SqlCommand(cadena1, conexion);
            comando1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        respuestaLabel.Text = ("Los datos se guardaron correctamente");
        conexion.Close();

    }
```

Comment: Qué valor inicial toma `folioTextBox.Text`? Seguramente inicia en 0, entonces cada vez que ejecutas `aumentoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` 0+1=1, por eso siempre toma 1. Debes buscar la forma de guardar tu folio anterior, y ese dato leerlo cada vez que se ejecuta `aumentoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras Que tal, lo que quiero logar es que solo me inserte una sola vez el numero 1 y al siguiente clic sea su consecutivo, ya logre que siendo día 1ro  el contador marque 1, pero lo hace cada vez que yo doy clic por que la condición así lo marca, lo que no eh logrado es que una vez insertado el 1 el siguiente clic sea su consecutivo

Comment: Entendí desde la primera vez. La cosa es que no será fácil: en algún lugar, de alguna forma, debes guardar registro del último folio usado; al inicio del evento `aumentoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` debes "leer" ese dato, y asignarlo al textbox. Lo que haces aquí es sumarle 1 al valor que ya tienes en el textbox (`folioTextBox.Text`), y yo te pregunté qué valor tiene ese textbox, y no respondiste.